How to render a texture in a unique color using SDL2?
(I apologize in advance for my awful English)
I'm writing a personal UI library in C++ using SDL2, and when came the moment to implement icons, I struggled to find how to render them in a unique color.
When creating an Icon object, the constructor loads the SVG as a SDL_Texture and then does a SDL_RenderCopy when the render() method is called. The Icon class also has a field for the color.
Suppose the initial SVG is black, how do I render the texture in e.g. white?
Thanks!

Have you considered making your SVG inputs white (changing the SVG markup directly if you need to) then modulating the colour when you draw the textures to the screen using SetTextureColorMod?

I tried to do so with one of them and it worked perfectly. But since I designed the icons myself, I'll have to recolor every single one of them, and they're about 125 :(

That should be possible to automate. If they're in plaintext SVG, you could do it with a regex search & replace using tools like Notepad++.

I considered doing just that. But the issue is that the SVGs are slightly different from one another. For some it's the stroke that's black, for others it's the fill. But I saw online that it is also possible to achieve the expected result by grayscaling the loaded SVG but unfortunately, I don't know how to do so :|

I don't see why that would pose a problem. Want to edit your question to include a sample of 2-3 sets of SVG code you're having trouble adjusting automatically?

Nevermind, I found out it's possible to have some kind of "color variable" in Illustrator, I'll just have to define a single color and apply it to all the icons and then change it to my liking. Thanks!

Want to write up your solution as an Answer post below? I bet it would be extremely helpful to the next developer who's trying to solve a similar problem.

In order to draw an SVG into the screen in any color in SDL2, the SVG needs to be initially white (if it's black, it won't work at all) then the SDL_SetTextureColorMod function must be called on the loaded texture alongside with the wanted color red, green and blue values.
In case you might need it, here is how to load an SVG in SDL2.
